# Theorem Style (like 1.1 Theorem)

Tags: amsthm

By default, theorems (using `amsthm`) are printed like *Theorem 1.1*. Is it possible to print them as *1.1. Theorem*? I have the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, dsfont,   amsthm , enumerate, graphicx, tikz,stmaryrd}
\newtheoremstyle{stelling}
{\topsep}   % ABOVESPACE
{\topsep}   % BELOWSPACE
{\itshape}  % BODYFONT
{0pt}       % INDENT (empty value is the same as 0pt)
{\large\bfseries} % HEADFONT
{.}         % HEADPUNCT
{5pt plus 1pt minus 1pt} % HEADSPACE
{}          % CUSTOM-HEAD-SPEC



\theoremstyle{stelling}
\newtheorem{theorem}[subsection]{Stelling}

\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}
Some text
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try inserting `\thetheorem. Theorem` as the last argument of `\newtheoremstyle`

Comment: Add `\swapnumbers` to the preamble.